# Revolution slider plugin assets not loading from CDN

Tags: wordpress, cdn, revolution-slider

I've integrated my WordPress site with Amazon CloudFront CDN. I'm using a plugin called Slider Revolution - Premium responsive slider (Version 5.4.8 by ThemePunch). For some reason, the JS files from this plugin are not loading from the CDN. These are the only remaining files that are not being loaded from the CDN.

GTMetrix's YSlow stats show the following as not being loaded from the CDN:

1. my-wp-site.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js?version=5.4.8
2. my-wp-site.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js?version=5.4.8
3. my-wp-site.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js?version=5.4.8
4. my-wp-site.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js?version=5.4.8
5. my-wp-site.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/assets/loader.gif

All the other plugins files are loading from the CDN. Is there something special I need to do or any way to debug what is going on here?